# function only returning one value instead of both in lua

Tags: lua, return, fivem

```
function GetCharacterName(source)
  local xPlayer = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayer(source)
  local name = xPlayer.PlayerData.charinfo.lastname
  local name2 = xPlayer.PlayerData.charinfo.firstname
    if xPlayer then
     return name, name2
    end
  end
```

I'm trying to return the values of name and name2, however the return is only giving the first value. I'm newer to lua, and code in general, so just trying to learn

Additional places in which this function is called:

```
   AddEventHandler("mdt:attachToCall", function(index)
   local usource = source
   local charname = GetCharacterName(usource)
   local xPlayers = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayers()
   for i= 1, #xPlayers do
       local source = xPlayers[i]
       local xPlayer = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayer(source)
       if xPlayer.PlayerData.job.name == 'police' then
           TriggerClientEvent("mdt:newCallAttach", source, index, charname)
       end
   end
   TriggerClientEvent("mdt:sendNotification", usource, "You have attached to this call.")
end)
```

```
RegisterServerEvent("mdt:performVehicleSearchInFront")
AddEventHandler("mdt:performVehicleSearchInFront", function(query)
    local usource = source
    local xPlayer = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayer(usource)
    if xPlayer.job.name == 'police' then
        exports['ghmattimysql']:execute("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `mdt_reports` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 3) sub ORDER BY `id` DESC", {}, function(reports)
            for r = 1, #reports do
                reports[r].charges = json.decode(reports[r].charges)
            end
            exports['ghmattimysql']:execute("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `mdt_warrants` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 3) sub ORDER BY `id` DESC", {}, function(warrants)
                for w = 1, #warrants do
                    warrants[w].charges = json.decode(warrants[w].charges)
                end
                exports['ghmattimysql']:execute("SELECT * FROM `player_vehicles` WHERE `plate` = @query", {
                    ['@query'] = query
                }, function(result)
                    local officer = GetCharacterName(usource)
                    TriggerClientEvent('mdt:toggleVisibilty', usource, reports, warrants, officer, xPlayer.job.name)
                    TriggerClientEvent("mdt:returnVehicleSearchInFront", usource, result, query)
                end)
            end)
        end)
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible reasons.

1. name2 is nil
2. you're using the function call in a way that adjusts the number of return values to 1. This happens `GetCharacterName(source)` is not the last in a list of expressions or if you put that function call into parenthesis or you assign it to a single variable.

#### Edit:

Now that you've added examples of how you use that function:

```
local charname = GetCharacterName(usource)
```

In this case the result list of GetCharacterName is ajdusted to 1 value (name) as you only assingn to a single variable. If you want both return values you need two variables.

Either do it like so:

```
local lastName, firstName = GetCharactername(usource)
local charName = lastName .. ", " .. firstname
```

Then charName is `"Trump, Donald"` for example.

Or you return that name as a single string:

```
function GetCharacterName(source)
  local xPlayer = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayer(source)
  local name = xPlayer.PlayerData.charinfo.lastname
  local name2 = xPlayer.PlayerData.charinfo.firstname
    if xPlayer then
     return name .. ", " .. name2
    end
  end
```

Then `local charname = GetCharacterName(usource)` will work

Comment: Possible ways to fix this?

Comment: what is the problem? 1. or 2.? I can't help you with so little code and information

Comment: name2 will populate a result if I put it first or remove name. I just can't get them both to give a result at the same time. So I'm assuming it's 2. the function of GetCharacterName() is called 7 other times in that script to define it's own local variable

Comment: please add some code that shows how you use that function to your question. that's much better than trying to explain what you do

Comment: Ok, I added 2 of the instances in which it gets called. It basically gets called in a similar fashion 3-4 additional times.

Answer (score 0):

local name1, name2 = GetCharactersName()

Comment: inputting that local crashes the server